# How to identify which shell-bag was last saved -- windows

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry

I am trying to identify which Windows 10 64-bit Shell Bag was most recently saved, but as I have 5000 Bags the "max bag" parameter from powershell is useless and the BagMRU key in the registry is a very deep tree (which identifies several dozen "last bags").

I'm working with the keys under HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags

Is there a powershell script that will identify the single last bag saved?

Comment: I saw this question yesterday.  Have you reposted it?

Comment: Yes it reposted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell which Bag was last used when there are 5000 of them - Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1772105/how-to-tell-which-bag-was-last-used-when-there-are-5000-of-them-windows-10)

Comment: Also this comment is applicable regardless of other considerations: https://superuser.com/questions/1772269/ffmpeg-script-to-scan-my-entire-content-folder-and-convert-the-videos-from-dts-a#comment2761598_1772269

Comment: "...he "max bag" parameter from powershell is useless ..."???  What are you trying to say???  What is the point of this?

Comment: "the max bag" parameter that is available in powershell only works if you have less than 5000 bags.  After that, you have to spelunk the barMRU rat-hole.

Comment: There is no "Max Bag" parameter in PowerShell. Speaking of a parameter without referencing a cmdlet makes no sense. There is an optional registry value to increase the limit. You can calculate the number of indexed nodes in BagMRU and I'm guessing you're talking about that. Are you wanting to try selective pruning as opposed to wholesale deletion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only get the the timestamp for the last time the key was modified. Using the [`RegQueryInfoKeyA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regqueryinfokeya) function:

> **`[out, optional] lpftLastWriteTime`**
>
> A pointer to a FILETIME structure that receives the last write time. This parameter can be NULL.
>
> The function sets the members of the FILETIME structure to indicate the last time that the key or any of its value entries is modified.

```
Add-Type @'
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class API
{
    [DllImport("Advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Error)]
    public static extern int RegQueryInfoKeyA(
        SafeRegistryHandle      hkey,
        uint p2,uint p3,uint p4,uint p5,uint p6,
        uint p7,uint p8,uint p9,uint p10,uint p11,
        ref long                lpftLastWriteTime
    );
}
'@

$KeyPath = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags'

Get-ChildItem $KeyPath | ForEach-Object -Process{
    [long]$lwt = 0
    [API]::RegQueryInfoKeyA(
        $_.Handle,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,[ref]$lwt
    ) | out-null
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'KeyName'   = $_.PSChildName
        'LastMod'   = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($lwt)
    }
} | sort LastMod -Descending
```

**Output**:

```
KeyName    LastMod
-------    -------
295        3/8/2023 03:19:13 AM
294        3/8/2023 03:16:28 AM
293        3/8/2023 03:16:18 AM
292        3/8/2023 03:15:25 AM
291        3/8/2023 03:14:28 AM
166        3/8/2023 03:14:23 AM
290        3/6/2023 02:47:23 AM
289        3/6/2023 02:29:46 AM
288        3/6/2023 02:29:03 AM
...
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a DIRECT answer but it is indeed an answer.

There is an amazing programmer named Eric Zimmerman that makes two tools along these lines.

ShellBags Explorer and SbeCmd (the command line version of this tool).

SbeCmd should be able to export the data you are looking for which you can read into powershell.

His code is written in .net so Powershell will be able to access the same features should you figure out "the magic" he is doing.  I myself would suggest reaching out to him to find out the secret as he seems like a cool person.

You can find his tools [here](https://ericzimmerman.github.io/) and if you should reach out to him, he will likely give you the answer to this question directly (via code) rather than my solution (via using his tool).

Answer (score 0):

Well, using ProcMon I have a brute-force answer.  Here's the procedure:

1. Start Procmon
2. Turn off Event Capture
3. Clear the screen
4. Set up a filter to be looking only at events from Explorer, and add a filter that the path include "bags"
5. Turn on Event Capture
6. Close an explorer window to save the bag you want
7. Turn off Even Capture
8. Look int he resulting list to find the bag type (key) you were looking for
9. Note that key's parent number

Of course, this is a one-off.  To more routinely/automatically find the last bag, a script of some sort would have to be written.